# Is $\lim_{M \to \infty} \int^1_{\frac{1}{M}} \frac{e^{-y}-e^{-2y}} y \, dy$ strictly greater than $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Is $\displaystyle \lim_{M \to \infty} \int^1_\frac{1}{M} \frac{e^{-y}-e^{-2y}} y \,dy$ strictly greater than $0$?

It is obvious that the limit should be non-negative, possibly infinite. But is it strictly larger than $0$. The strategy might be to find a lower bound of the integral which tends to a number strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: Did you mean $M \to 0$?

Comment: In any case, looking at $\int_1^2 e^{-sy}\,ds$ allows to evaluate the integral exactly.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $\frac{1}{M}$

Comment: Then use Fubini? and take the limit in?

Comment: Yes, Fubini and limit. And after that, look up Frullani integrals.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. But still do you have an argument that can indirectly show it is positive?

Comment: Sure. The integrand is strictly positive on $(0,1]$, so the integral also is strictly positive.

Comment: But taking limit might push it to zero, right?

Comment: Oh, I see, if I use Fubini as you suggested first, this problem can be avoided.

Comment: Increasing $M$ makes the interval of integration larger. So for $M \geqslant 2$ we have $$\int_{1/M}^1 \frac{e^{-y} - e^{-2y}}{y}\,dy \geqslant \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{e^{-y}-e^{-2y}}{y}\,dy.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{M \to \infty} \int^1_{\frac{1}{M}} \frac{e^{-y}-e^{-2y}} y dy&=\lim_{M \to \infty} \int^1_{\frac{1}{M}}\int_1^2e^{-xy}\:dx\:dy
\\
&>\lim_{M \to \infty} \int^1_{\frac{1}{M}}\int_1^2e^{-2y}\:dx\:dy
\\
&=\lim_{M \to \infty} \int^1_{\frac{1}{M}}2e^{-2y}\:dy
\\
&=\lim_{M \to \infty} (e^{-2/M}-e^{-2})
\\
&=1-e^{-2}>0
\end{align}